Puppeteer unable to click an element in iFrame while emulating mobile
Please take a look at the two Puppeteer scripts below.
Both of them are opening https://elarto.pl/logowanie, waiting 7 seconds for a pop-up window to appear and then trying to close the pop-up by clicking on the "X" icon (#edrone-onsite-popup-content > div > div > div:nth-child(2) in the edrone-onsite-popup-iframe iframe).
The first one is able to click the element ("STEP 3").
The second one is not.
The only difference is that the second one is emulating a mobile browser.
What am I doing wrong?
(Please ignore the step 4).
Script 1 - DESKTOP:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const fs = require('fs');

async function run() {
    let page_frame, frames, frame;
    let found = false;
    let element = null;
    let step = -7;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-zygote', '--lang=pl'],
        defaultViewport: null
    });

    step = -6;

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Accept-Language': 'pl'
    });

    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1366,
        height: 950,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1
    });
    await page.setUserAgent(await browser.userAgent() + ' TESTING');

    step = -5;

    page.on('error', function(err) {});

    page.on('pageerror', function(err) {});

    step = -4;

    let response = await page.goto('https://elarto.pl/logowanie', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 180000
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(null);
        browser.close();
        process.exit();
    });

    if (response === null) {
        response = await page.waitForResponse(() => true);
    }

    step = -3;

    if (response === null) {
        console.log(null);
        browser.close();
        process.exit();
    } else {
        console.log(response.status());
    }

    step = -2;

    if (response.status() != 200) {
        browser.close();
        process.exit();
    }

    step = -1;

    try {

        // STEP 1

        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 1;

        if (found === false) {
            try {
                element = await page_frame.$('button.btn-primary:nth-child(1)');

                if (element !== null) {
                    await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                        element.scrollIntoView({
                            block: 'center',
                            inline: 'center'
                        });
                    }, element);
                    await page_frame.click('button.btn-primary:nth-child(1)');

                    found = true;
                }
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        if (found === false && 0 === 0) {
            console.log('RESULT:PROCESS (1)');

            browser.close();
            process.exit();
        }

        // STEP 2

        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 2;

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 7000));

        // STEP 3

        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 3;

        frames = await page.frames();
        frame = frames.find(f => f.name() === 'edrone-onsite-popup-iframe');

        if (frame) {
            page_frame = frame;
        }

        if (found === false) {
            try {
                element = await page_frame.$('#edrone-onsite-popup-content > div > div > div:nth-child(2)');

                if (element !== null) {
                    await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                        element.scrollIntoView({
                            block: 'center',
                            inline: 'center'
                        });
                    }, element);
                    await page_frame.click('#edrone-onsite-popup-content > div > div > div:nth-child(2)');

                    found = true;
                }
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        if (found === false && 0 === 0) {
            console.log('RESULT:PROCESS (4)');

            browser.close();
            process.exit();
        }

        // STEP 4

        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 4;

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));

        if (found === false) {
            try {
                element = await page_frame.$('aegsrg');

                if (element !== null) {
                    found = true;
                }
            } catch (e) {}

            if (found === false) {
                try {
                    element = await page_frame.$x('aegsrg');

                    if (element.length > 0) {
                        found = true;
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
            }

            if (found === true && element !== null) {
                await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                    element.scrollIntoView({
                        block: 'center',
                        inline: 'center'
                    });
                }, element);

                var elContent = await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                    return element.innerHTML;
                }, element);

                if (elContent.indexOf('') < 0 && 0 === 0) {

                    console.log('RESULT:PROCESS (5)');

                    browser.close();
                    process.exit();

                }
            }
        }

        if (found === false && 0 === 0) {
            console.log('RESULT:PROCESS (5)');


            browser.close();
            process.exit();
        }


    } catch (err) {
        let err_code = null;

        if (err.message.replace(/'/g, '').indexOf('Execution context was destroyed') !== -1) {
            err_code = 'execution_context_was_destroyed';
        }

        if (err_code !== null) {
            console.log('RESULT:PROCESS (' + step + ')|' + err_code);
        } else {
            console.log('EXCEPTION:' + err.message.replace(/'/g, ''));
        }

        await browser.close();
        process.exit();
    }

    console.log('RESULT:OK');

    await browser.close();
};

run();

Script 2 - MOBILE:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const mobile = puppeteer.KnownDevices['iPhone 7'];

const fs = require('fs');

async function run() {
    let page_frame, frames, frame;
    let found = false;
    let element = null;
    let step = -7;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-zygote', '--lang=pl'],
        defaultViewport: null
    });
    
    step = -6;

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ 'Accept-Language': 'pl' });
    
    await page.emulate(mobile);
    await page.setUserAgent(mobile.userAgent + ' TESTING');
        
    step = -5;

    page.on('error', function (err) {
    });

    page.on('pageerror', function (err) {
    });
    
    step = -4;

    let response = await page.goto('https://elarto.pl/logowanie', {
        waitUntil : 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 180000
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(null);
        browser.close();
        process.exit();
    });
    
    if (response === null) {
        response = await page.waitForResponse(() => true);
    }
    
    step = -3;
    
    if (response === null) {
        console.log(null);
        browser.close();
        process.exit();
    }
    else {
        console.log(response.status());
    }
    
    step = -2;
    
    if (response.status() != 200) {
        browser.close();
        process.exit();
    }
    
    step = -1;
    
    try {

        // STEP 1
        
        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 1;

            if (found === false) {
                try {
                    element = await page_frame.$ ( 'button.btn-primary:nth-child(1)');

                    if ( element !== null ) {
                        await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                            element.scrollIntoView({block: 'center', inline: 'center'});
                        }, element);
                        await page_frame.click ( 'button.btn-primary:nth-child(1)' );
                            
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {}
            }

            if (found === false && 0 === 0) {
                console.log ('RESULT:PROCESS (1)');

                browser.close(); process.exit();                                                         
            } 

        // STEP 2
        
        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 2;

            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 7000));
        
        // STEP 3           
        
        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 3;
                    
        frames = await page.frames();
        frame = frames.find(f => f.name() === 'edrone-onsite-popup-iframe');
            
        if (frame) {
            page_frame = frame;
        }
    
            if (found === false) {
                try {
                    element = await page_frame.$ ( '#edrone-onsite-popup-content > div > div > div:nth-child(2)');

                    if ( element !== null ) {
                        await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                            element.scrollIntoView({block: 'center', inline: 'center'});
                        }, element);
                        await page_frame.click ( '#edrone-onsite-popup-content > div > div > div:nth-child(2)' );
                            
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {}
            }

            if (found === false && 0 === 0) {
                console.log ('RESULT:PROCESS (4)');

                browser.close(); process.exit();                                                         
            } 

        // STEP 4
        
        page_frame = page;
        found = false;
        element = null;
        step = 4;

            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));

            
                if (found === false) {
                    try {
                        element = await page_frame.$ ( 'aegsrg' );
                            
                        if (element !== null) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                    
                    if (found === true && element !== null) {
                        await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                            element.scrollIntoView({block: 'center', inline: 'center'});
                        }, element);                                

                        var elContent = await page_frame.evaluate((element) => {
                            return element.innerHTML;
                        }, element);
                        
                        if ( elContent.indexOf ( '' ) < 0 && 0 === 0 ) {

                            console.log ('RESULT:PROCESS (5)');

                            browser.close(); process.exit();                                     

                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if (found === false && 0 === 0) {
                    console.log ('RESULT:PROCESS (5)');

                    browser.close(); process.exit();                                                                     
                }
                


    }
    catch (err) {
        let err_code = null;
        
        if (err.message.replace(/'/g, '').indexOf('Execution context was destroyed') !== -1) {
            err_code = 'execution_context_was_destroyed';
        }

        if (err_code !== null) {
            console.log ('RESULT:PROCESS (' + step + ')|' + err_code);
        }
        else {
            console.log('EXCEPTION:' + err.message.replace(/'/g, ''));
        }

        await browser.close();
        process.exit();
    }
    
    console.log('RESULT:OK');
    
    await browser.close();
};

run();


Lots of complex code here. Are you sure these examples are minimal, and there is no unnecessary code here? Avoid booleans and deeply nested conditions. This code is really hard to follow.

@ggorlen You are right. I just removed some unnecessary parts of the code. What's important here is the "STEP 3" that is working as expected on desktop, but it's not working on mobile.
